# Is there a torrent software that doesn't require installation?

Tags: windows-xp, bittorrent

I'd like a torrent client that doesn't require installation and can run of an exe. Is there such a software ? If not, is it possible to install it onto a thumb drive and then be able to run it on a different machine ?

Comment: Your search term will be PORTABLE. Google PORTABLE UTORRENT.

Comment: I use a portable version of uTorrent and SSH VPN Tunnel through my home network connection. Business doesn't like torrents so I traffic my data through the home connection. However, anything illegal is still illegal. Hopefully, you're just trying to download a few Linux ISOs or something while at school/work/coffeehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://torrentfreak.com/utorrent-portable/) you can find an example:

1. [Download](http://www.utorrent.com/download.php) the latest standalone version, and copy it onto your datastick.
2. Create an empty datafile with notepad or any other text editor, and name it settings.dat
3. Place the settings.dat file in the same folder on your portable disk as uTorrent.
4. Run uTorrent from your portable drive and confugure the options and preferences.

Now you’re ready to go. You can start downloading at school, and finish at home. And the good thing is that you don’t need to install uTorrent or another BitTorrent client, just a USB-port, that’s all you need.

If you’re planning to use uTorrent on different computers with different bandwidth settings, make sure that you set the maximum upload speed to 90% of the available upload speed to guarantee fast download speeds.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Opera Web Browser](http://www.opera.com/browser/features/#popular) it has a client built into it, but you still need to download and install Opera.

> Download using BitTorrent
>
> Support for BitTorrent is built in to Opera, so you can download torrents without the need for a separate application. You can even monitor the progress of large torrent downloads with Opera’s Downloads panel.